# Making textbox to declare aliases

Tags: vb.net

Just to start: Has Anyone played Counter Strike 1.6 ?
Question: There you can declare  alias `(Alias a "+right")`. 
i would like to do the same, but with windows cmds (Windows 7), and add the commands to vb.net program.
Example: `alias stopit "shutdown -a"`

(i have it connected with rainmeter so the box stay's in the screen at all times)
YES i have tryed to google it, found nothing.

Comment: you need to be clearer about what you want to do. WHAT are you trying to alias?  Whatever it is has to already exist in the program (be it a command, function, operation etc).

Comment: I would like to alias the commands of cmd.exe
The clearer question would be:
How do i declare a function for every command i am going to use?
Any examples from you?

Comment: `Dim StopIt As String = "cmd shutdown -a"`  now I have a string to send to CMD "aliased" as StopIt.  Now where does the textbox come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [OFFTOPIC]I've played for many years CS 1.6, but this is kinda
>   different from what a game console means.[/OFFTOPIC]

The only way to manage this is by setting a new environment variable on the system, then use the environment variable on the CMD, the variable value should contains the command instructions.

PS: Of course this kind of changes requires the CMD to reset (close and reopen), otherwise you couldn't use new aliases until you reopen the CMD.

So here we go:

```
Public Class Test

    ' Textbox to set new alias.
    Private WithEvents TBSetAlias As New TextBox With
    {.Location = New Size(Me.Top, Me.Left), .Dock = DockStyle.Top}

    ' Button to save alias.
    Private WithEvents BTSaveAlias As New Button With
    {.Location = New Point(Me.Top, Me.Left + TBSetAlias.Bottom),
     .Text = "Save", .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}

    ' Parts of the alias (name, command)
    Private AliasParts As String() = {String.Empty}

    ' Name of the alias 
    Private AliasName As String = String.Empty

    ' Command of the alias 
    Private AliasCommand As String = String.Empty

    ' SendMessageTimeout Constants
    Public Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF&
    Public Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = &H1A
    Public Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

    ' SendMessageTimeout API function
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.
    DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SendMessageTimeout(
                  ByVal windowHandle As IntPtr,
                  ByVal Msg As Integer,
                  ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
                  ByVal lParam As String,
                  ByVal flags As SendMessageTimeoutFlags,
                  ByVal timeout As Integer,
                  ByRef result As IntPtr
    ) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' SendMessageTimeoutFlags Enum
    <Flags()> _
    Public Enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags As Integer
        SMTO_NORMAL = &H0
        SMTO_BLOCK = &H1
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2
        SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = &H8
    End Enum

    Private Shadows Sub Load() Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Load the controls into UI
        Me.Controls.AddRange({TBSetAlias, BTSaveAlias})

        ' Set the textbox text alias
        TBSetAlias.Text = "alias dirfiles ""dir /B *.*"""

    End Sub

    Private Sub TBSetAlias_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles TBSetAlias.TextChanged

        AliasParts = sender.text.split

    End Sub

    Private Sub BTSaveAlias_Click() Handles BTSaveAlias.Click

        If AliasParts Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf AliasParts.Count > 1 Then

            Select Case AliasParts.FirstOrDefault.ToLower.Trim

                Case "alias"
                    AliasName = AliasParts(1)
                    AliasCommand = String.Join(Convert.ToChar(Keys.Space),
                                               AliasParts.Skip(2)).
                                               Replace(ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty)

                    ' Set an environment variable
                    SetEnvironmentVariable(AliasName, AliasCommand, Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser)

                Case "else"
                    ' Is not a valiad alias
                    Throw New Exception("Invalid Alias.")

            End Select

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub SetEnvironmentVariable(ByVal VariableName As String,
                                      ByVal Value As String,
                                      ByVal RootKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey)

        Select Case RootKey.Name

            Case Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.Name
                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment",
                                              VariableName,
                                              Value,
                                              Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)

            Case Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.Name
                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment",
                                              VariableName,
                                              Value,
                                              Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
        End Select

        ' Update System Change
        SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, _
                           WM_SETTINGCHANGE, _
                           0, _
                           "Environment", _
                           SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, _
                           100, _
                           IntPtr.Zero)

    End Sub

End Class
```